# Firebug - How to start in JS debug mode when page loads

Tags: javascript, debugging, firefox, firebug

I'm looking at a web page where when I push the submit button on a form, it brings up a new page where it runs some javascript and then closes the window.

Is there any way I can step through the javascript on the new page?  I tried setting break on next in Firebug on the first page, but the next page still closes the window.

(I'm open to other tools besides Firebug if neccessary, I just need to step through the javascript)

Update:

I should have mentioned I don't have access to the code :-(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have access to the code, you can place this little statement where you want to have a breakpoint:

```
debugger;
```

I am not sure about firebug, but I expect it to work there too.

Comment: It kinda looks like the developer console / firebug needs to already be open for this to work. That doesn't have to be a problem if you know about it. This also works in chrome.

Answer (score 1):

put `debugger;` in your JavaScript code. and press `F12` key just after window open.